# Add a second Y-axis for labels using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to create a final graph similar to something like this:
[image]

But where there would be only one blue label value per month which would be `Nb_diff` the difference between the green bar chart (positive) and red bar chart (negative).
[image]

Additionnaly, if the values of the green and red bar charts could be shown right above the each bar chart would be great.
I am struggling to add a second Y-axis for the `Nb_diff` value.

Here is the data for reproducibility: https://github.com/max9nc9/Temp/blob/main/net_delta_all_Monthly.csv
And here is the ggplotly I tried to create. Side note, I saw that geom_label might be incompatible with plotly so what is the workaround if I want to use plotly?

```
net_delta_all_Monthly_Graph <-
ggplot(net_delta_all_Monthly, aes(x=Date, y=Nb_Delta, fill=NetPositiveorNeg)) + 
  geom_bar (stat="identity", position = position_dodge() ) +
  geom_label(aes(label=Nb_Delta), size = 4, position = position_dodge(1),  color = "white" ,fill ="#0f5af2")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#b80009", "#34b800")) +
  labs(y = "Number of Net Lines") +
  labs(fill = "Net Lines")+
  labs(title = "Number of Net Created & Net Deleted Lines") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(caption = paste0("Data updated on ", format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y")))

net_delta_all_Monthly_Graph
net_delta_all_Monthly_Graph <- ggplotly(net_delta_all_Monthly_Graph)
```

Thanks.